# When the new baby arrives how do you help the oldest sibling adjust?

Tags: siblings, newborn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I cope with my toddler’s jealousy towards her newborn brother and sister?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/825/how-do-i-cope-with-my-toddlers-jealousy-towards-her-newborn-brother-and-sister)

Sibling rivalry **will** occur, but there must be preventative things that can be done to help the first child to be more accepting of the arrival of the second and get the sibling relationship started on the right foot.

What practices did you use that you believe to have made a difference with your own kids?  What do you wish you had done because you think things may have been easier if you had?

Comment: This feels a little like a duplicate of this - http://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/825/316 - what do you reckon?