# Preventing jealousy from starting?

Tags: toddler, newborn, jealousy

My question is similar to this [question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/825/how-do-i-cope-with-my-toddlers-jealousy-towards-her-newborn-brother-and-sister) but not exactly the same. We are having our second child very soon. We have a 2 year old daughter and she is already beginning to understand that change is coming. I have read/heard nightmare stories about the jealousy of the first child against newborns. While we still have a chance, how can we potentially prevent or at least decrease any high levels of jealousy and resentment towards the new child by my daughter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spend one-on-one time with your daughter, as much as you can.  Important now, while the sibling is still on his/her way, but critical once he/she gets here.

Also, find ways to include her in the day-to-day care of her new sibling.  Can she fetch wipes/diapers/bibs?  Would she want to help feed, when bottles are appropriate?  Maybe she can  do some coloring for the baby?  My daughter, who was a little less than three when her brother arrived, loved drawing pictures to put into his crib in NICU, and when he was home, we posted them on his walls.